# How do I pronounce the letter "y" in words?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is the letter Y in 'by' pronounced 'bai' but in 'Tyrion' it's 'Tirion' and not 'Tairon'?

Comment: Because all vowels in English have multiple pronuncitions, and not all of them are easy to predict. (For example, the "i" in _wind_ can be pronounced two ways, depending on whether you are talking about the breeze or putting your yarn into a ball.) In this case, the "y" in _Tyrion_ is like the "y" in _syrup_.

Comment: Uhmm, like _Life_ and _Live_, right?

Comment: There are also some words that could be pronounced two ways even though it's written exactly the same. **Either** could be pronounced as "E-ther" and "I-ther". I also heard there are up to seven ways to pronounce the word **tomato**.

Comment: @Franchesco Or like _live_ and _live_, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pronunciations of Y are correct and often found in English, because English is influenced by many different languages. Many of its words have decidedly different origins and pronunciations, but because English only has so many characters in its alphabet, different sounds inevitably get represented by the same letters sometimes.

Examples of /aɪ/ ("long I") pronunciations:

- Spy
- Cry
- Lyre

Examples of /iː/ ("long E") pronunciations:

- Ably
- Funny
- Fifty

In fact, Y can be pronounced other ways as well. For example, *synonym* pronounces Y as /ɪ/ ("short I", as in *kit* or *lid*).

As for *by* and *Tyrion* specifically, the pronunciations differ because the words have different etymologies. *By* comes from [Old English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English), which is a West Germanic language <sup>[1](http://dictionary.reference.com/etymology/by), [2](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=by&searchmode=none)</sup>, while *Tyrion* (I assume, I don't know the thought process behind the writer of *Game of Thrones*) comes from *[Tyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BDr)* which is North Germanic/Old Norse.

The two words are also structurally different. *Tyrion* has multiple syllables while *by* has only one; the Y in *by* is at the end, whereas in *Tyrion* it's not; etc. All of these things can influence pronunciation.